# PHP Facebook logout

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk) for creating facebook login, which works fine but when I want to logout and I use [getLogoutUrl](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/4aab0548d16749b41eb27d7e02b3872b1c9c24b1/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php#L156) method which returns logout url in this form:

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout?next=google.com&access_token=my_access_token
```

After I redirect to this page I get to the **This page is not avalible** page on FB and I am not logged out. Any idea what could be wrong ? or it will be SDK bug ? thanks.

Comment: Did you specify an actual, full URL for the `next` parameter?

Comment: Yes I did. `$facebook->getLogoutUrl($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'], 'https://www.google.com')` and I still get page not found.

Comment: It has to be a URL that matches your app’s domain settings; you can not just redirect to any arbitrary location you like.

Comment: The Url must be in Valid OAuth redirect URIs ? I tried to add it there but it didn't help

Answer (score -1):

I have created a article for facebook login logout with graph api with php. You can see the following code for logout from facebook with php. This is code for **logout.php**

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['fb_access_token'])){
    require_once 'php-graph-sdk-5.5/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => 'app-id', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
      'app_secret' => 'app-id-secret',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
    ]);
    $url = 'https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=your-website-return-url/&access_token='.$_SESSION['fb_access_token'];
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: '.$url);
}
```

If you need full source code then you can see this [link](https://github.com/surajkumardotin/facebook-login-logout-with-php)

Comment: The problem is that `https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=your-website-return-url/&access_token='.$_SESSION['fb_access_token']` this format of URL simply gives me page not found response on facebook.